# Error verifying developer key while integrating testlink and jenkins

Tags: python, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, robotframework, testlink

I am trying to integrate robot framework with testlink and jenkins. I followed [this](http://alans09.blogspot.com/2016/02/robot-framework-jenkins-testlink.html) link for the integration.

I was able to perform all the steps without any issue till it comes to integrate testlink with jenkins. I am getting following error:

```
Preparing TestLink client API.
Using TestLink URL: http://localhost:8012/testlink/lib/api/xmlrpc/v1/xmlrpc.php

FATAL: Error verifying developer key: Failed to read server's response: Connection refused (Connection refused)
br.eti.kinoshita.testlinkjavaapi.util.TestLinkAPIException: Error verifying developer key: Failed to read server's response: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at br.eti.kinoshita.testlinkjavaapi.MiscService.checkDevKey(MiscService.java:63)
    at br.eti.kinoshita.testlinkjavaapi.TestLinkAPI.<init>(TestLinkAPI.java:144)
    at hudson.plugins.testlink.TestLinkBuilder.getTestLinkSite(TestLinkBuilder.java:307)
    at hudson.plugins.testlink.TestLinkBuilder.perform(TestLinkBuilder.java:186)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:735)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:206)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:163)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:490)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1735)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:405)
Caused by: org.apache.xmlrpc.XmlRpcException: Failed to read server's response: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcStreamTransport.sendRequest(XmlRpcStreamTransport.java:161)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcHttpTransport.sendRequest(XmlRpcHttpTransport.java:143)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcSunHttpTransport.sendRequest(XmlRpcSunHttpTransport.java:69)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClientWorker.execute(XmlRpcClientWorker.java:56)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClient.execute(XmlRpcClient.java:167)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClient.execute(XmlRpcClient.java:158)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClient.execute(XmlRpcClient.java:147)
    at br.eti.kinoshita.testlinkjavaapi.BaseService.executeXmlRpcCall(BaseService.java:90)
    at br.eti.kinoshita.testlinkjavaapi.MiscService.checkDevKey(MiscService.java:60)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:463)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:558)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:242)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:339)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:357)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1220)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1156)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1050)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:984)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1334)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1309)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcSunHttpTransport.writeRequest(XmlRpcSunHttpTransport.java:104)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcStreamTransport.sendRequest(XmlRpcStreamTransport.java:151)
    ... 20 more
ERROR: Error communicating with TestLink. Check your TestLink configuration.
Recording test results
Finished: FAILURE
```

I see this file:

```
# find . -name xmlrpc.php
./var/www/html/testlink/lib/api/xmlrpc/v1/xmlrpc.php
```

When I open the Testlink URL `http://localhost:8012/testlink/lib/api/xmlrpc/v1/xmlrpc.php`, it opens a blank page. I am not sure where is the issue. Can someone please help me in resolving this issue?

Comment: Did you check TestLink configurations?   Docker ports could be good to check also, using cURL example.

Comment: Sometimes tracing the actual traffic with WireShark or other network logging applications can give some more detail, but it appears that the connection is refused and that can be because there is a firewall or if it's a docker container trying to connect to the 'outside' world, that it requires more configuration to allow the outbound traffic.